# How do I start a discussion about a page on TWiki?

Tags: twiki

I'm used to Wikipedia's Wiki, and now that I'm using TWiki at work I really miss the ability to discuss a page outside the page but still on TWiki.

Have I missed a button or link somewhere? Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MediaWiki (Wikipedia and the like), every page has a discussion page associated with it. This is not the case in TWiki, at least not by default. The administrator can built something similar, but as a user, all you can do is manually create and link discussion topics.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can reuse the template code in http://foswiki.org/Extensions/TalkContrib on foswiki - I've not used TWiki in years, but foswiki is a compatible fork.

Sven